# cache: 'no-store' does not work in nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a server component in **nextjs**. I want to send a request to **API** to get data every time this page is loaded. that's why I apply `{ cache: 'no-store' }` to fetch and also
set `revalidate to 0`, but It does not work. the first time It requests to **API** and in the second and third and .. does not
send request.

I think it fetches data from the cache.

**NOTE**
I added `import 'server-only'` but does not affect it.

```
import 'server-only';

async function getPosts() {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/posts', { cache: 'no-store' })
    return res.json()
}

export const revalidate = 0;

export default async function ServerPage() {
    const posts = await getPosts()

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Server Props...</h2>

            <ul>
                {posts && posts.map(({ id, title, body }) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={id.toString()}>
                            <strong>{title}-{id}</strong>
                            <p>{body}</p>
                        </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

How can I solve my problem ?

Comment: If you are using app directory(beta) then by default all the files inside app are server components so you dont need to use server-only but you need to use use-client whenever you want it to be client component.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'`, which will solve the problem (did for me as I wasn't using the fetch method but apollo client), as by default all pages are static, though the no-caches that you applied should have worked.

Also, you may need to add `export const revalidate = 0`, as well to fetch it on every request.

Answer (score 1):

'no-cache' and 'no-store' produce different results for me. On the documentation it says "The no-cache option behaves the same way as no-store in Next.js". However when i put 'no-store' on a statically generated page fetch request i get this error “Entire page... deopted into client-side rendering." When i put "no-cache" on the fetch i dont get that error, and the page is still an SSR page.

I think its because no-cache will cache the response, but client will check server before using that cached data

So try "no-cache"

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple test with `next@13.4.1`, the `cace: 'no-store'` works as expected.

```js
// utils.ts
export async function getTodo(id: number) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`);
  return res.json();
}

// app/page.tsx
import { getTodo } from '../utils'

export default async function Page() {
    const task = await getTodo(1);
    return (
        <div>home page</div>
    )
}

// app/todo/page.tsx
import { getTodo } from "../utils"

export default async function Page() {
    const task = await getTodo(1);
    return (
        <div>todo page</div>
    )
}
```

With cache enabled, and request the todo with id 1 from different pages, the output in console

```bash
-  ┌ GET / 200 in 1659ms
   │
   └──── GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 200 in 1529ms (cache: MISS)

- wait compiling /todo/page (client and server)...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 576 ms (625 modules)

-  ┌ GET /todo 200 in 1169ms
   │
   └──── GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 200 in 2ms (cache: HIT)
```

When set cache to `no-store`, and request the todo with id 1 from different pages, the output in console

```bash
-  ┌ GET / 200 in 3272ms
   │
   └──── GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 200 in 2737ms (cache: MISS)

- wait compiling /favicon.ico/route (client and server)...
- event compiled successfully in 240 ms (301 modules)
- wait compiling /todo/page (client and server)...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 329 ms (625 modules)

-  ┌ GET /todo 200 in 939ms
   │
   └──── GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 200 in 413ms (cache: MISS)
```

Maybe you made the same request on the same page, in that condition, **your requests get deduped**

> By default, all fetch() requests are cached and deduplicated automatically.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching#automatic-fetch-request-deduping

Comment: How do you configure the console log to see the requests? E.g. GET / 200 in 3272ms. Mine doesn't show them

Comment: @ekimpl That's the default logging output of nextjs-cli, I hadn't made extra config

Comment: to print out fetch log at server side, turn on the experimental config https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/src/server/config-shared.ts#L166